# How to make comunication between javascript and desktop aplication in C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, web

I want to create windows application which will wait for http requests and after some action, response with some value. It will be asynchronized calls. And i want to call that application from my web application, probably with javascript. How i can make request for localhost:someport and wait for response in javascript?

Comment: Is the web application also running on local host? Or will this be a cross-domain request?

Comment: Why not just use SignalR.  Then you can wait as long as you want between request/response.

Comment: "I want to create windows application which will wait for http requests" - You will have to host httpserver in your Windows application. Checkout Katana self hosting option with httplistener.

Comment: @Wet Noodles, no, web application will be hosted on intranet, and every computer will have instaled desktop aplication, it will bi like windows servise, which will call a desktop api, when web application calls localhost and port. that is how i imagined it, but i dont know javascript so much.

Answer (score 3):

You can just call it with any library that provides you ajax calls. Below goes an example using jQuery:

```
 $.ajax( "http://localhost:2020/" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

In your "client app" that is acting as a "server" for http requests, you have to include this header in the response to allow the cross-domain call:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
```

Comment: but what is a code for that call? i think i will know to handle that in c# app, i dont know how to write it in javascript.

Comment: @user3549602 I added example code to call localhost using ajax.